# create jwt token in c# asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, token

I'm trying to create JWT token after user login 
I'm doing this according to the following project:
https://github.com/CodAffection/JWT-Authentication-with-.Net-Core-Web-API-and-Angular-7/branches

My App fails on string

> var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

I get error

> Internal Server Error
>   An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10603: Decryption failed. Keys tried:
>   '[PII is hidden]&#x27

Here is the full code from controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    //Post: /api/ApplicationUser/Login
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        //  var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserName);
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user!=null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]{
                    new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                //   Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.key)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };


            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            return Ok(new { token });   
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "username or password is incorrect." });
        }
    }
```

I've read different manuals but could not find the problem, also my code is completely the same as the project I'm trying to replicate. Please tell me in which way to dig if possible :)

Comment: and what is the error being returned?

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: IDX10603: Decryption failed. Keys tried: &#x27;[PII is hidden]&#x27;.

Comment: Have you assigned the secret key properly?

Comment: I'm putting secret key string dirrectly instead of _appSettings.key but that won't help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is correct! but I think, your secret key doesn't have enough characters to create an access token. Just increase the secret key length, it will work fine.

Updated: For HmacSha256Signature, Secret key length should not be less than 128 bits; in other words, it should have at least 16 characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code sample that I use to build a jwt token server side:

```
 private string BuildToken(User user)
    {
        var userSerialise = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, userSerialise)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          claims,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
          signingCredentials: creds);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    }
```